# calling setPie shows "other" slice eventhough i disabled it

Tags: zoomcharts

I have a zoom pie that can go 4 levels deep.
In my settings object i have this:
            interaction: { others: { enabled: false } },
which effectively disabled the "other" slice.
I implemented my own breadcrumbs and when the user clicks on it, i call setPie(level, offset) to zoom out to the correct level.
This works fine, the only problem is that for some odd reason, whenever the setPie api method is called, it always shows the "other slice", and if there would be only one slice, it shows the "other" slice as 100% and only when i click on it, i get back the normal slice. And this despite the fact that I disabled it (or i thought i did) altogether.
Please advice.

Thank you,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What value are you using for the `offset` parameter? In your case it should be `0`, if you pass in other value, then the "Previous" slice might be shown.

See http://jsfiddle.net/t7q65o7n/

Comment: This works great, thank you so much! For some reason when i first developed it, it didn't work unless i calculated the offset, but after reading your reply i followed your suggestion and it works like a charm!